# Expressjs server and external api calls

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm new to frontend development and express server. When I tried to start an express.js server with react (with axios calls to external apis), it seems express.js is adding 'localhost:3000' in front of the external API calls so they fail.

In my server.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '.', 'dist');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is up!');
});
```

Which leads to the API call to **[www.example.com/api/](http://www.example.com/api/)** to become **http://localhost:3000/www.example.com/api/**

I also tried to filter the req by writing:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  if (req.url.match(/\/api\//) === null) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
  }
});
```

But it does not change things...
Can anyone help out this newbie that is me?

**Update1** Adding the code for calling the api:
This is the api call:

```
const getSomething = () => {
  try {
    const url = endpoints.GET_SOMETHING;

    return axios.get(url);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

endpoints.GET_SOMETHING is the api URL: **[www.example.com/api/getSomething](http://www.example.com/api/getSomething)**

Comment: Could you add the code you are using to call the api?

Comment: You don't show your front end code, but if you want to make a request to a different host or port than the web page was loaded from, then you need to construct a full URL such as `http://myhost:4000/mypath` and use that full URL with the request.

Comment: Is there in html have you a baseurl tag? If yes then remove it :)

Comment: Thx for all your comments! It did need a full URL and it now works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a `/` in the url

```js
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});
```

and also your endpoint url should start with `https://`, `http://` or `//`

Comment: Thx! It's working now! That's much simpler than I thought... was in the middle of looking at making a proxy with http-proxy-middleware and found your answer and it's all working like a charm now